# Can one marry halachically in New York State without a marriage license?

Tags: wedding

Can an Orthodox rabbi marry myself and my fiance without a marriage license? If so why have 2 rabbis already said no to me? Is it because they are certified by NYS and obligated to report? I need to know if we can get married without a civil marriage license

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Jewish Aduly, and thanks for the interesting question! And if you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Now your question might well get closed because MY does not provide answers to specific personal situations (see the tour) but don't let that discourage you from staying and learning with us.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25870/need-for-civil-marriage-license-in-the-frum-world

Comment: Seems like the law obligates one to get a license (e.g., first point [here](http://www.cityclerk.nyc.gov/html/marriage/license.shtml)) so I cannot imagine people would provide advice here to go around the law. See also  ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites)
 to better understand how MY works

Comment: I have met people who have married le-halacha (according to Jewish law) but have not married civilly because of a delay in the civil divorce even though the get was written and delivered. **However** they were required to marry civilly as soon as it became possible in order to avoid the legal problems mentioned. At the very least they had to make an appropriate neder to do so (which made it a halachic requirement as well) . Nowadays it is often considered a tnai of the kiddushin.

Comment: My wife and I could not be in her home town early enough to meet the waiting time requirements (then in effect). As a result, we got a New York City civil license which my then rebbi signed (as he was authorized to do) and we made a neder to really get married at the time scheduled for the real wedding. The civil marriage license was dated correctly and was used to fulfill the requirements of civil law. Otherwise the civil authorities would treat matters as if the couple was "just living together" and all laws of inheritance and spousal responsibilities do not apply.

Comment: @sabbahillel http://www.rabbis.org/news/article.cfm?id=105834

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71011/does-ny-state-hold-that-a-ketuba-is-a-marriage-license/71012#71012  I show that New York State requires a civil marriage license by law.