# Jewish (Lubavich) view on only halochik marriage (no government documentation)

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, marriage, chabad

Some one told me the chabad Rebbe was against marriage that was only halachakli (and not recognized by the government)

Is this true? Source?
What of the opinions of other rabbis on this matter? (sources please)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68284/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25870/759